# Angular 2 main component not loaded when import feature modules but load the component in feature module that not exported

Tags: angular

I have a feature module is `noi-dung.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";

import { NoiDungListComponent } from "./noi-dung-list/noi-dung-list.component";
import { NoiDungService } from "./shared/noidung.service";
import { NoiDungRoutingModule } from "./noi-dung.routing";

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, NoiDungRoutingModule],
    declarations: [NoiDungListComponent],
    providers: [NoiDungService]
})
export class NoiDungModule {
}
```

And I import it to my AppModule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';


//feature module
import { NoiDungModule } from './noi-dung/noi-dung.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    NoiDungModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I get this error

```
"Template parse errors:
'my-app' is not a known element:
1. If 'my-app' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'my-app' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("

<body>
    [ERROR ->]<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>

"): NoiDungListComponent@27:4"
```

It tell me that the `my-app` selector is not in the `NoiDungListComponent` 
But I am not exports that component in the `noi-dung.module.ts`

And the `my-app` selector is in the `AppComponent`

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector:'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app/app.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'App Angular 2 Base';
}
```

The `AppComponent` is the one bootstrap and declare in main module

So why it loaded the `NoiDungComponent` which is inside `noi-dung module` and not exported outside but not the component that declared and bootstrap ?

**[EDIT] GOT THE ANSWER IN THE COMMENT**

Comment: Somehow looks like you have `<body>
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>` inside a component instead of only in `index.html`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer you are right, A typo in noi-dung-list component that call the wrong template, so the server return the index.html, thanks you, I got panic spend hours finding, think of SO and got answer right aways, thanks very much haha :D

Comment: Glad to hear. Was a rather wild guess, but the error seemed too weird ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<body>
  <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
```

should only be in `index.html` not in a components template.